# C++ CRT Memory Leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am having a problem with lots of memory leaks.

CRT shows leaking in the following code for example:

```
char *cmd = new char[128];
```

What should I do?

```
char *cmd = new char[128];
delete[] cmd;
```

I started new project with VLD (Visual Leak Debugger) with the code above and it still says I am leaking.

Comment: Sure i delete this reference after all

Comment: Yes, i do that for sure, but CRT shows im still leaking

Comment: Which compiler is this? Show more code, perhaps this is in a loop and not all are being cleaned up

Comment: Are you using Microsoft's `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`? In my experience, this does not play nice with C++ `new`/`delete` calls. So it is possible that you have no leaks at all, actually (but equally likely that you do) ;)

Comment: I use VLD that is framework on CRTDebug, well IDE is Visual Studio 10

Comment: How about using `std::string` ?

Comment: i need to use char, cuz i use tcp/ip protocol.

Comment: @Griwes: "Also, why the hell are you even using" Because he doesn't have black belt in C++ and is not aware of std::vector, yet, duh.

Comment: It is difficult to know what the problem is from your isolated code fragement. Please reduce your program to the smallest possible program that still displays the memory leak. If you still don't understand what it going on post that **small** (hint: less than 20 lines) program in your question. See http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you need to free the memory as soon as you stop using it.

Some good C++ techniques for automating this are [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) and [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

Also consider Wikipedia article on [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: @Hakon89 the problem is that the memory is not reclaimed to the system. You should return the resources you don't use anymore via `delete` operator, otherwise your program and OS will feel bad.

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling `delete[] arrayVariable;` and not `delete arrayVariable;` to avoid memory leaks that are to do with arrays.

Comment: Yes, i do delete[] instead of just delete

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your objects are deleted after the leak detection runs.

For instance, if you have static objects, you have to pay attention to the deletion order so that their deletion occurs before the leak detection occurs.

Try to embed the new/delete in a function and see if the leaks are still reported: if not, then the problem may indeed be related to the objects being deleted after the leak detection has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
std::vector<char> cmd(128);
```

Whenever you need access to the char* buffer you can do:

`char* memory = &char[0]` as memory is guaranteed to be continue for std::vector.
No need to delete because memory is owned by the object. This makes your code also exception safe, e,g, you will not leak memory in case there is an exception thrown before you do the delete []

You can also use the new std::array from C++11 also if you want to allocate on the stack